# Difference between the following two different passing variables method into functions

Tags: c, function

I have the following struct and two kinds of methods listed below. Which method is better and why?

```
typedef struct _MY_ST_
{
  int a;
  int b;
} MY_ST;
```

Method 1:

```
int func1(MY_ST my_st)
{
  int temp;
  temp = my_st.a + my_st.b;
  return temp;
}
```

Method 2:

```
int func2(const MY_ST *const my_st)
{
  int temp;
  temp = my_st->a + my_st->b;
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: Your question title and your question in your post are different questions. Neither is "better"; any advantage or disadvantage of *either* is entirely dependent on intended usage, which is not specified whatsoever. So clarify your question: Better *for what* exactly? There is an obvious *difference*: one passes by-value the other passes by `const` address (also a value, just a different kind). One allows local modification  of structure data, the other does not. On has no mechanism to refer to the *caller's* data directly, the other does, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With such a small structure (2 integers), you won't see a difference.

In general, though, it usually makes sense to pass a pointer to the structure, since it avoids unnecessary copying. But in this specific case, I'd say just go with whatever you're more comfortable with and makes sense for you.

Also, you don't need the parameter in `func2()` to be `const MY_ST *const my_st`. `const MY_ST *my_str` will suffice, because the pointer is passed by copy, so there is no way that the callee will modify the caller's pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the second method is better because you only pass a pointer to the memory where your structure is held. In the first method you pass the who structure and the computer will duplicate in memory the structure in the function - a copy of the structure will be made. (but a compiler running optimization may make the two methods equivalent)